# GWT Celltable with data in map

Tags: gwt

I have my datas as a `Map<Key,ArrayList<Value>>` So i want my col1 to represent my key and the other columns to represent data in my values. And this Value can be or multiple rows. So i was thinking of putting a celltable inside a celltable but then it will affect my headers(since the number of columns for the outer celltable will be just 2) and also the sorting.

And also if i pass the map directly to `ListDataProvider` it assumes the number of rows is the number of rows of the map but it is not the case.

So what is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a class RowObject like this:

```
class RowObject {
    private final Key key;
    private final Value value;

    RowObject(Key key, Value value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    /* Getters omitted */
}
```

Then convert the map to a list of RowObjects and feed the list to the data provider:

```
List<RowObject> rowObjects = new ArrayList<RowObject>();

for (Entry<Key, ArrayList<Value>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    for (Value value : entry.getValue()) {
        rowObjects.add(new RowObject(entry.getKey(), value));
    }
}

ListDataProvider<RowObject> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<RowObject>();
dataProvider.addDataDisplay(cellTable);
dataProvider.setList(rowObjects);
```

Add columns like this:

```
Column column = new Column<RowObject, String>(new TextCell()) {

    @Override
    public String getValue(RowObject object) {
        return getStringValueFor(object);
    }
};

cellTable.addColumn(column);
```